# Bibliography LaTeX et al

Tags: cite-package

Please, which latex bibliography will I use to have my citation as, e.g. [mashroom et al. 2008], and I want the year 2008 to be in blue 'hyperlink'.Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE community. Please share a MWE related to your query.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Your question is not clear since you did not specify exactly which bibliography style you want. Assuming that you want to use `natbib` with `IEEEtranN`, then this is a good starting point for you to understand how it works

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@article{aldaoudeyeh2016,
    title={{Photovoltaic-battery scheme to enhance PV array characteristics in partial shading conditions}},
    author={Aldaoudeyeh, Al-Motasem I},
    journal={IET Renewable Power Generation},
    volume={10},
    number={1},
    pages={108--115},
    year={2016},
    publisher={IET}
}
@ARTICLE{wu2017,
    title={{Assessing Impact of Renewable Energy Integration on System Strength Using Site-Dependent Short Circuit Ratio}},
    author={Wu, Di and Li, Gangan and Javadi, Milad and Malyscheff, Alexander M and Hong, Mingguo and Jiang, John Ning},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Sustainable Energy},
    year={2017},
    publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{wu2019,
    title={A method to identify weak points of interconnection of renewable energy resources},
    author={Wu, Di and Aldaoudeyeh, Al Motasem and Javadi, Milad and Ma, Feng and Tan, Jin and Jiang, John N and others},
    journal={International Journal of Electrical Power \& Energy Systems},
    volume={110},
    pages={72--82},
    year={2019},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[square]{natbib} % natbib is very common and reliable bibliography management package

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue3, citebordercolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true} % link color of citations goes here


\begin{document}

\citep{aldaoudeyeh2016} % \citep is used to meet the style you want [Author et al., year]

\citep{aldaoudeyeh2016,wu2017}

\citep{aldaoudeyeh2016,wu2019,wu2017}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN} % style of bibliography (here you specify that you want authoryear or numeric citation)
\bibliography{sample} % defines the file that contains information about the article you cite

\end{document}
```

**Note:** you need to use a .bib file. You can either create it using `filecontents` environment or by placing that file in the same directory of the .tex file you work with. Google Scholar, journals, and conferences provide BibTeX style info for articles and conferences proceedings.

Also, the LaTeX file you use will generate a set of files whose name is very similar to the '.tex' file you use and in the same directory. If you want to change your bibliography style, the changes will usually not apply unless you remove a file whose type is '.bbl' and its name is the same as your '.tex' file